# Arrastar e Mudar a Posição de um GroupBox em Tempo de Execução

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um groupbox que desejo que o usuário consiga arrastar e mudar a posição em tempo de execução, alguém imagina alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Windows Forms ou WPF?

Comment: Em Windows Forms

Comment: mudar a posição do groupbox ou dos itens dentro dele?

Comment: Preciso de um comportamento como se fosse um DOC, tenho um groupbox com alguns botões dentro dele, gostaria que o Usuário pudesse ser capaz de mover esses botoes conforme o gosto dele para deixar aonde ele quiser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não existe nada pronto pra isso no Windows Forms, mas é possível trabalhar com os eventos do *mouse* e localização de controles para ter este efeito.

Eu tenho aqui uma classe com extensões que faz exatamente isso. Eu lembro que precisei pra um projeto e encontrei ela em algum blog, vou procurar o autor pra dar os devidos créditos. A propósito, ela talvez tenha sido modificada.

A única coisa que é necessário para fazer um controle ficar "arrastável" é **`controle.Draggale(true)`** e **`controle.Draggale(false)`** para desativar.

Veja em funcionamento.

[image: GIF de um groupbox sendo arrastado pela tela]

```
public static class ControlExtension
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Control, bool> Draggables 
                                             = new Dictionary<Control, bool>();
    private static Size _mouseOffset;

    public static void Draggable(this Control control, bool enable)
    {
        if (enable)
        {
            if (Draggables.ContainsKey(control))
            {
                return;
            }
            Draggables.Add(control, false);

            control.MouseDown += control_MouseDown;
            control.MouseUp += control_MouseUp;
            control.MouseMove += control_MouseMove;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!Draggables.ContainsKey(control))
            {  
                return;
            }

            control.MouseDown -= control_MouseDown;
            control.MouseUp -= control_MouseUp;
            control.MouseMove -= control_MouseMove;
            Draggables.Remove(control);
        }
    }

    private static void control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _mouseOffset = new Size(e.Location);
        Draggables[(Control)sender] = true;
    }

    private static void control_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Draggables[(Control)sender] = false;
    }

    private static void control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Draggables[(Control) sender])
            return;

        var newLocationOffset = e.Location - _mouseOffset;
        ((Control)sender).Left += newLocationOffset.X;
        ((Control)sender).Top += newLocationOffset.Y;
    }
}
```

Comment: muito bacana =]

Comment: Muito obrigado era exatamente isso.

Comment: Excelente LINQ !

Answer (score 6):

Olhando rápido aqui, começaria pelo evento `MouseMove`:

```
 public Form1()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    groupBox1.MouseMove += groupBox1_MouseMove;
 }
```

...

```
    void groupBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            groupBox1.Location = e.Location;
        }

    }
```

> O evento não é exibido na interface gráfica do vs, então tens de adicionar via código, no construtor ou evento load do form.

e

> É só o começo da implementação... desse jeito ainda não fica legal, o controle fica piscando quando arrasta e pela a localização do mouse, sem considerar a localização inicial, mas já é um começo. Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 0):

Aproveitando o Código do Amigo "Rovann Linhalis", ajustei as minhas Necessidades:
Criei um button com name btn_arrastar e atribui o evento MouseMove.

```
void btn_arrastarMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        btn_arrastar.Location = new Point(Control.MousePosition.X - btn_arrastar.Size.Height/2,Control.MousePosition.Y - btn_arrastar.Size.Width/2);
    }
}
```